# How do I send a different automated email for each different product purchased on paypal?

Tags: email, paypal

Without using "Buy Now" buttons, I want to send my customers a unique email for each different product purchased with a download link to a file (encrypted obviously).

So if they purchased 2 different songs, I want to be able to send 2 automated emails with different download links.

I have searched for ages and don't know how to do it. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to send two individual e-mail to your customers and also to customise your email options you can make use of Instant Payment Notification(IPN).

`Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, like fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status.`

You need a listener file in your server, so when a paypal transaction is made, paypal will send you the transaction response (with all required transaction information) so, in your listener file you can build your own logic of sending multiple e-mails to your buyers.

You can get sample IPN listener codes in [Github](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples)